# how to use Wcf in communication between the desktop and WP7?

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi new person to the **wcf** .. I have one confusion that if i use the WCf whether i need to maintain the server. Or its not required. please explain clearly.. Actually ...I want send the some files to phone modify in the phone app resend back to desktop app. Is there any alternative to do this without server.

Comment: explain what.  What do you mean by maintain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WCF to connect to Windows Phone 7, you are going to need a "server" of some sort.  I think since you are new to WCF, you should probably start with learning the basics of WCF.  Once you get up to speed on the basics, you will have a better handle on how to deal with issues like this in the manner best suited to your environment.

Here is a quick quote from Microsoft's site on what WCF services are all about:

> WCF is Microsoft's next-generation programming platform and runtime system for building, configuring and deploying network-distributed services.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480190.aspx

Basically, if you are designing network-distributed services, you need them to be installed on a central server.  This is especially true if you are communicating to mobile devices.

Comment: I want send the some files to phone, modify in the phone app resend back to desktop app. Is there any alternative to do this without server? Because in android and balckberry i can use sockets for communication, but in WP7 not support socket.